# Чудовищный трафик с named по порту 53 UPD

Tags: fedora, dns

Итак, у хостера, когда трафик зарубежный превышает трафик российский, включается счетчик и он начинает снимать за трафик деньги. Проблема в том, что мой днс на сервере взбесился и начал рассылать и получать данные из разных уголков света накручаивая зарубежный трафик на 15Gb в день. Я поколдовал с named.conf и мне удалось уменьшить трафик до 5-7Gb. Вот конфиг файл:

```
controls {    inet 127.0.0.1 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };};logging {        channel "log_default" {        file "/var/log/named.log" versions 10 size 10m;        severity info;        print-time yes;        print-severity yes;        print-category yes;        };        channel "log_security" {        file "/var/log/named-security.log" versions 5 size 10m;        severity info;        print-time yes;        print-severity yes;        print-category yes;        };        channel "null" {        null;        };        category "default" { "log_default"; };        category "security" { "log_security"; };        category "unmatched" { "null"; };};//acl trusted {//      127.0.0.1;//};options {        //allow-recursion {        //      trusted;        //};        //allow-query {        //      127.0.0.1;        //      217.16.0.0/24;        //};        //allow-recursion {        //      any;        //};        allow-query { 127.0.0.1; };        allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };        allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1; };        recursion no;        dump-file       "/var/log/named_dump.db";        statistics-file "/var/log/named.stats";        directory "/var";        //auth-nxdomain no;        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";};key "rndc-key" {        algorithm hmac-md5;        secret "CeMgS23y0oWE20nyv0x40Q==";};controls {        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };};zone "." {        type hint;        file "named.root";};zone "0.0.127.IN-ADDR.ARPA" {        type master;        file "localhost.rev";};zone "25.200.82.in-addr.arpa" {        type master;        file "25.200.82.in-addr.arpa";        allow-transfer {                common-allow-transfer;        };};
```

Домены указывать не стал, так как это не важно. Все дело осложняется тем, что на сервере стоит fedora 4 и походу она настолько стара, что скачать под нее софт практически невозможно, по крайней мере, из репозитория. Подскажите, что делать? Мне подсказали, что проблема может быть в рекурсии, но я ее отключил, поэтому, скорее всего, трафик уменьшился, но все равно еще слишком высок. Как проверить, отключилась ли рекурсия на самом деле?

Comment: Если есть tcpdump, поставьте его на пару часов, сохраните вывод в файл. Отсортируйте по ip адресам, хотя бы поймете что откуда и куда.

Comment: Я уже 2 дня мониторю основной трафик идет на  srv-u41.antiddos.biz  ns3038.hostgator.com stats.windflower.arvixe.com поддомены меняются иногда...

Comment: немогу закрыть фаерволом их почемуто!

Comment: Это с вашего сервера запросы идут на эти хосты или наоборот?

Comment: Я так понял сначала на сервер с них приходит запрос потом в ответ приходит и почемуто исходящий трафик с сервера в разы больше входящего...

Comment: А есть возможность указать определенные подсети с которых можно принимать запросы, я имею ввиду не технически а принципиально, т.е есть ли такие подсети или это глубоко публичный сервис?!

Comment: Что то на ddos атаку смахивает. Проверьте ip вашего сервера в блеклистах. Сервисов в интернете полно.А вообще глянуть бы вывод tcpdump.

Comment: Решил проблему так: позвонил провайдеру отрубил зарубежный трафик на неделю, за это время перетащу все днс на яндекс или еще куда. Провайдер сказал что это флуд на dns сервер.

Comment: "когда трафик зарубежный превышает трафик российский" надо начать накручивать российский?))) http://ithappens.me/story/417

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xakep.ru/post/59335/Может быть, тут схожая ситуация описана?